# Using two select fields to filter a acf relationship field (ACF)

Tags: wordpress, relationship, advanced-custom-fields

My question is similar to this one, but I want to take it a step further.

[Update select field in repeater based upon the choice of other select field (ACF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35812451/update-select-field-in-repeater-based-upon-the-choice-of-other-select-field-acf)

I have two acf select fields in my admin area and relationship field.  The two select fields are each loaded with a custom taxonomy.  The first is called "Pool" and the second is "Month".  A pool can be one of these values "A,B,or C".  The month field is just the month of the year.  The relationship field displays all of the posts from a custom post type.

When I select a pool, I see the results in the relationship being filtered which is great.  When I select a month, I can see them being further filtered.  All good news.  I click the update button on the post and my values are saved.

There are two issues that I am having.

First, When i come back to the page, my filters have not been activated.  I am using wp_ajax calls to update the relationship field.

Secondly,  When I come back to edit this same post, I can see all posts in the left side of the relationship field and the ones i have selected on the right side.  When  I interact with the my pool and month filters all of the results on the left side of relationship field change like they should except the problem is the ones i have selected and appear on the right side already are now also  appearing on the left side again and they are not disabled.

Ultimately, what I would like to do is when I edit the page, I want my filter to be active already.  This means the relationship field should be filtered with the selection i have already chosen before i saved.

I also want to have the values I have already selected to be disabled on the left side if they appear on the right side.

What do i need to do to make this work?

**admin_site.js**
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

```
jQuery('.tips-pool select, .tips-month select').change(function(){

    var tipsPoolSelected = jQuery('.tips-pool select').val();
    var tipsMonthSelected = jQuery('.tips-month select').val();

    console.log("tipsPoolSelected: " + tipsPoolSelected);
    console.log("tipsMonthSelected: " + tipsMonthSelected);    

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'filter_by_tips',
            tips_pool_selected: tipsPoolSelected,
            tips_month_selected: tipsMonthSelected,
        },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (result) {
            //Use the html to populate your time select field
            jQuery('.tips-relationship .selection .choices ul.acf-bl.list').html( result );
            console.log("result: " + result);
        },
        error: function (errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });

});

});
```

**functions.php**

```
// Function to hook into from the select
add_action('wp_ajax_filter_by_tips', 'filter_by_tips');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_by_tips', 'filter_by_tips');

/**
 * Get the tips filter by pool cat id
 */
function filter_by_tips(){
  global $wpdb;

  $html_select = NULL;

  // pool_cat_slug
  if($_POST['tips_pool_selected']){
    $pool_cat_slug = $_POST['tips_pool_selected'];
  }

  // month_cat_value
  if($_POST['tips_month_selected']){                        
     $month_cat_slug = strtolower($_POST['tips_month_selected']);
  }

                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'daily-marriage-tips',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'cat_tips',
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => $pool_cat_slug,
                        ),
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'cat_months',
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => $month_cat_slug,
                        ),
                    ),
                );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $query->have_posts() ):
      while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $post_title = get_the_title();

        $html_select = '<li><span class="acf-rel-item" data-id="'.$post_id.'">'.$post_title.'</li>';

        endwhile;
    endif;

    if($html_select){
      echo $html_select;
    }   

    unset($pool_cat_slug);
    unset($tips_month_selected_array);

    exit;
}
```